# Different ways to set url path in base tag in mvc website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i am just passing url like this in my MVC website:

```
<base href="http:4546//localhost/" />
```

It works in local but if i am hosting it on ISS.This url creates issues.

If i am removing 4546 in url like this:

http://localhost/Home/Contact

Then its working.

I tried it by removing port number in code but still in url port number displays itself.

how i can remove port number or what will be the way so i can host it with port number 80  on public?

Please let me know where i am lacking.

Thanks

Comment: why don't you use `@Url.Action()` helper?

Comment: Take a look at `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`

Comment: should i need to change everywhere in code?

Answer (score 6):

You can create one Base Controller and add this method

```
 protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            var request = HttpContext.Request;
            var baseUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", request.Url.Scheme, request.Url.Authority, HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath == "/" ? "" : HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath);
            ViewBag.BasePath = baseUrl;
  }
```

This method OnActionExecuting will always be called on each request and user this viewbag in you code.

This will resolve your issue of writting every where in code.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar issue where, on certain IIS configurations, the `base` tag (which is necessary for AngularJS) was providing the incorrect address.  The way I got around this is by replacing `<base href="/">` with:

```
<base href="@(string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}/", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority, HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath == "/" ? "" : HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath))">
```

This is basically a shorter version of Sulay's solution, but it has worked for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

My need to set `base` tag stems from using AngularJS as it requires `base` for correct routing, if html5 mode is on.

I ended up with this method:

```
private const string Action = "action";
private const string Controller = "controller";

public static string CurrentActionWithoutRouteReuse(this UrlHelper urlHelper)
{
    var routeValues = urlHelper.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;
    var actionName = (string)routeValues[Action];
    var controllerName = (string)routeValues[Controller];

    var routeValuesWithoutParams = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);
    routeValuesWithoutParams.Remove(Action);
    routeValuesWithoutParams.Remove(Controller);
    routeValuesWithoutParams.Keys
        .ToList().ForEach(parameterName => routeValuesWithoutParams[parameterName] = null);

    var url = urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValuesWithoutParams);

    return url.EndsWith("/") ? url : url + "/";
}
```

Note, here I explicitly set other params to `null`. That is because of route reuse which MVC uses, but I didn't need at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just adding this in your page?

```
<base href="~/">
```

This will be replaced when compiled by your URL path. I do that to make routing work for my Angular (2+) app and it works fine.